# Get location information from twitter using processing

Tags: java, twitter, location, processing, twitter4j

I'm trying to write a program in processing that can get a location from the user who is using Twitter. In every twitter profile there is information where they live like "New York, NY". I figuered out that I will need to use Twitter4J to do this, but what im really asking, is it possible to get a users location from their profile? or is it limited to only induvidual tweets?

I don't expect a full code as an answer but if somebody can point me in the right direction it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest also using 
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java
for OAuth integration (very easy to integrate and extend) and then load user profile.

twitter user profile contains all details, including user's location, see example below

```
...
"location":"Oslo, Norway"
,"geo_enabled":true
...
```

see twitter api -> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

Comment: Im not that very good at java so I don't know how to use the info from the link in processing. I've tried using the getLocation() but get a "null" in the printline.